# Android send curl request to Heroku with option

Tags: android, curl, heroku, httpclient

Using Android, I am trying to send a curl request with this format:

```
curl http://appname.herokuapp.com/send -d "user_id=pPPu4yZap2&title=hello&body=message to mjpablo23"
```

I am trying to use the AsyncHttpClient: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-Android-Async-Http-Client

I have the url set up like so:

```
String url = "http://appname.herokuapp.com/send -d ";
```

I call the http client like this:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
params = new RequestParams();
String user_id = "pPPu4yZap2";
params.put("user_id", user_id);
params.put("title", "the title");
params.put("body", "the message");
client.post(url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        });
```

However, I'm not sure what to do about the -d option.  Should I be including it in the URL?  Is post the right command to use?

I am getting this error in Android:

```
Process: com.android.todo4group, PID: 27042
                                                                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 45: http://appname.herokuapp.com/register -d 
                                                                            at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:733)
                                                                            at com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient.getURI(AsyncHttpClient.java:1542)
```

Comment: pay close attention to the syntax/ idiom of asynchttpclient ( it does not use -d ) .. note that u are mixing syntax from curl and its "-d" switch into a diff , android api for http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need the -d option in the url.  -d is an option in curl that means include data.  By sending params, I am including the data in the httpclient call.  It works after taking out the -d.